# Mobius transformation producing a curved triangle with 3 intersecting circles

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, mobius-transformation, mobius-inversion

> Let $ABC$ be a curved triangle on a plane, whose side $AB$, $BC$ and
>   $CD$ are arcs of circles $S_1$, $S_2$ and $S_3$ passing though a point $D$ (i.e. $S_1∩S_2∩S_3 = D$, $D≠A$, $D≠B$, $D≠C$). Assume that the angles at the vertices $A$ and $B$ are $30$ degrees each. Find the angle at the vertex $C$.

---

I really do not understand how to do this. There is a hint to simplify the problem with the appropriate Mobius transformation, but I am completely lost. How are we meant to know what specific Mobius transformation leads to a certain result (in this case, three circles that intersect at one point)? Any help is greatly appreciated.

By this question [Möbius Transformation of Triangles](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/591862/m%C3%B6bius-transformation-of-triangles), the answer says that "the image of your triangle is a triangle with circular arc sides, which DO meet at the same angles that the sides of the triangle did"

I am confused by what this means, since it implies that the angle at vertex $C$ is $120$ but curved triangles have a sum of angles $>180$. I am sure it is applicable in some way to my situation, though.

Answer (score 2):

We know that Mobius transformations transform generalized circles into generalized circles. Now, our 3 circles meet at a point which is not on the triangle. If we now think of this point as an element of $\mathbb{C}$ (in the obvious way- we take a point $(a,b)$ to $a+bi$), we can always find a mobius transformation which sends this point $D\in\mathbb{C}$ to infinity- say, $z\mapsto \frac{1}{z-D}$. Note that each of the circles we have transform to a generalized circle, but they all share the point $D$ which is mapped to $\infty$. Hence, they cannot be mapped to circles, and they must be mapped to lines. The 3 arcs we have will be mapped to 3 lines, which have pairwise intersection at certain points- i.e, a triangle. As the transformation is conformal, the angles are preserved at the intersection points- that is, in the vertices of the triangle. So now we can finish, as the sum of angles in a triangle is $180$.

As for what you said in the end, this shows that some curved triangles have angle sum $=180$. Some do not.